# Changing member of list impacting copy of the list

Tags: python

Running below code

```
x = [1, [2,3, [4,5,6]]]
y = x[:]
x[0] = 55   # impacted only x
x[1][0] = 66   # impacted x & y
x[1][2][1] = 79   # impacted x & y
print(x,y)
```

This code gives the result as below

```
[55, [66, 3, [4, 79, 6]]], [1, [66, 3, [4, 79, 6]]]
```

`x[0] = 55` not impacted y. But `x[1][0] = 66` & `x[1][2][1] = 79` impacted both x & y. What is the correct reason?

Comment: Because [:] copy the list x, but the inner list still point to the same list.

Comment: Because `y = x[:]` makes a ***shallow copy***. So you get ***list aliasing*** when you assign to its elements that are sublists.

Answer (score 2):

When you copy x into y, the inner list is not copied. In other words, x[1] and y[1] are pointing to the same object.

visualizing your code at http://www.pythontutor.com/ should help to understand